# Updating children of non-child component

Tags: reactjs

I have an app structure that looks a bit like this...

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/introduction' component={Introduction} />
        <Route path='/guide/:slug([a-z0-9-]+)' component={Guide} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

When the `/guide/...` route matches, the `Guide` component needs to load a guide and then somehow populate the `children` prop of the `Header`, in order to add the guide’s title and table of contents to the global app header.

I know I can use React’s context API or a state object in my root `App` component to achieve this. This however would require all other components to undo these changes when another route loads.

Alternatively I could add another `<Switch>` block inside `Header` and have a `GuideHeader` component that works independently of the `Guide` component, but that would require loading the guide’s content twice. (Not the end of the world if it’s cached, but still.)

What’s the most optimal way for `Guide` to update the `Header` in this case?

Comment: If you will use React's context API you can undo changes in `componentWillUnmount` function inside `Header`.

Comment: What's your `Guide` component implementation? In Header `componentDidUpdate` check the `/:param` if it matches `guide route` fetch the state of guide via an exported function.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are looking for a central store where data updates should map to the components. You can integrate [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) state management for this case.

Redux will provide the data to header whenever there is an update to the key in the central store. You will have to subscribe to the key from the header component to know about updates.